# GWT Material: Unexpected text in element: "? ?"

Tags: gwt-material-design

Copying code from gwt-material's github demo (gwt-material-demo) you can receive this strange error in compile-time:

```
[ERROR] 12477 [main] INFO org.jboss.errai.enterprise.rebind.NonGwtEventQualifierSerializerGenerator - Successfully loaded org.jboss.errai.cdi.EventQualifierSerializerImpl
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for '[my_packages].Binder'
[INFO]       Rebinding [my_packages].Binder
[INFO]          Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
[INFO]             [ERROR] Unexpected text in element: "? ?": <m:MaterialRow> (:21)
```

This is due to some strange unvisible characters as shown in this picture:

[image]

Removing them, everything is okay.

Bye
Nicola

Comment: Yes, I ran into this a couple times too. Probably lost a couple hours... never thought it was indentation.

Comment: @NicolaBen you should post your solution as an answer